# Finding invalid tuple path in list

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, tuples

I am currently on my last step of writing a program about finding gradient ascent between coordinates. After loops and a lot of if statements, my program finds the correct path. I am now tasked with finding the invalid steps in the path.

```
[(0, 5), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 1), (5, 1), (5, 0)]
```

As we can see in this tuple, this is what my function gets for the path. The path is only valid if the first or second element for each consecutive index is one less or one greater, however, it cannot happen to both elements in one step. The first 3 steps in the indexes look good, with (0,5) going down 1 to (0,4), then (0,4) going up 1 to (1,4), then (1,4) going to (2,4). For (3,3), this step is invalid, because although it goes 1 number up or down, it did so for both elements. I want to write a loop to find these invalid steps:
Here is what I have tried:

```
path = [(0, 5), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 1), (5, 1), (5, 0)]
fin = []
for i in path:
    for j in i:
        if path[i+1][j] - path[i+1][j] != -1 or path[i+1][j] - path[i+1][j] != 1:
            fin.append(path[i])
```

This does not work. I don't have much python knowledge regarding indexing, so I am struggling to find an efficient solution. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens after finding the first invalid path?(as per your logic rest of them are also invalid)

Comment: Sorry if I explained it awfully, but the rest, after the (3,3), are not invalid. Upon going to the next step, as long as one number out of the 2 in the tuple remains the same, and the one that changes only goes up or down one unit, it is valid. I think once you find that first invalid path, it is automatically invalid, and just prints the two tuples where the invalid step occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
path = [(0, 5), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 1), (5, 1), (5, 0)]
invalid_steps = []
for index, step in enumerate(range(len(path)-1)):
    x0, y0 = path[index]
    x1, y1 = path[index + 1]
    valid_step = {0,1}
    x_move = abs(x1-x0)
    y_move = abs(y1-y0)
    if not {x_move, y_move} <= valid_step or x_move == y_move == 1:
        invalid_steps.append(path[index+1])
```

`Out: [(3, 3)]`

Comment: This actually fits very well with my other code. It is very easy to understand and I was able to add some stuff to give some more complex output. Thank you so much!